# Mongodb findbyIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm a little nervous, but this code makes me angry.
Well, i am trying to save my img src attribute in mongodb using findbyIdAndUpdate, but only inputs works correctly.

**Route JS**

```
    //Update user profile route
router.put("/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.user,  function(err, updatedUser){
        console.log(req.body.user);
    if(err) {
        res.redirect("/:id");
        console.log(err);
    }   else {
        res.redirect("/set/"+req.params.id);
        console.log("Great!");
    }
    })
});
```

**User Schema**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true},
    password: String,
    googleid: String,
    avatar: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    phone: Number,
    city: String,
    street: String,
    office: String,
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
});
```

Html update form

```
...
   <img id="avatar" name="user[avatar]" src="<%= user.avatar %>" alt="...">

...                  

   <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="user[firstName]" class="form-control border-input" value="<%= user.firstName %>">
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but only inputs works correctly.`?

Comment: only when i use these method on inputs fields, like <input type="text" name="user[firstName]"

Comment: can you paste the value of `user.avatar`?

Comment: from mongo you mean?

Comment: img element is not one of the form's supported elements. List of supported elements is here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp To achieve what you want you could add the src value to a hidden input just before submitting

Comment: well, i`ve thought about this method and i really sad about it